# CSS / HTML5 to align this checkbox and text?

Tags: css

I'm having some difficult trying to make it appear like this (screenshot below)

[image: example]

I'm pretty new to CSS. Can I put .item anywhere inside the custom CSS file?

Here's the HTML code of the way it looks right now

```
<div class="item">Add a photo:<br>
  <%= f.file_field :image %>
  <br>
   <label for="a">Rename photo?</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="a"></div><br>
```

Comment: What's wrong? It's already showing like this http://jsfiddle.net/BcEB7/

Comment: @Morpheus - I think he wants the "rename photo?" and checkbox to the right, not under.

Comment: Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/BcEB7/3/), as [Morpheus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1716463/morpheus) said, it is already showing what he wants.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `float: right` to the elements you want to the right, like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="item">Add a photo:<br>
  <%= f.file_field :image %>

   <label class="to_right" for="a">Rename photo?</label>
  <input class="to_right" type="checkbox" id="a"></div><br>
```

CSS:

```
.to_right
{
    float: right;
}
```

As show here:
http://jsfiddle.net/7P7R5/

Answer (score 0):

Create separate div htmls:

```
<div class="ItemContainer">
    <div class="ItemInput">Add a photo:<br>
        <%= f.file_field :image %>
    </div><div class="ItemCheckbox">
        <label for="a">Rename photo?</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="a">
    </div>
</div>
```

And use `display:inline-block;`:

```
.ItemInput,.ItemCheckbox {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.ItemCheckbox {
    margin-left:10px; /* Or whatever you want */
}
```

This will have the div's inline with one another, while maintaining block properties that you can manipulate. This is more effective than floats because there is no need to clear them with the phantom div, and it is a WYSIWYG display type.

An example [jsFiddle is provided here](http://jsfiddle.net/jv5tS/4/).

The `vertical-align` is just to make it appear at the top, you can set it to whatever you'd like. I also set up the classes and container like that just in case you wanted multiple instances of this input. If you only have the one, you can just give them the same class with no container.

**EDIT:** included `margin-left` on `.ItemCheckbox` to provide a little separation.

Comment: It wasn't me. I'm close but this is what I'm getting http://i.imgur.com/FIpTKJc.jpg. Also, I tried border-left: 10px; for .ItemCheckbox and I can't create space between the two. Do you know how I can best fix this?

Comment: Just add a `margin-left` to the `.ItemCheckbox` CSS. I set it to `10px` in my example, but you can do whatever you'd like. I also updated the jsFiddle link (it has `background-color` to show the separation).